# How to get formaction in submit event?

Tags: javascript, html

Having a simple form with two submit buttons, how can I get the `formaction` attribute in a `submit` event?

HTML code:

```
<form id="FORM" action="/original">
  <input type="text">
</form>

<button form="FORM">original</button>
<button form="FORM" formaction="/formaction">formaction</button>
```

When submitting using `formaction` button `action` of the form is still original in the event.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/a80wnex6/

Comment: Code is working fine (thx for example code), but my problem is how to get the new action set by `formaction` inside a `submit` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the overridden form `action` by grabbing the element which currently has focus (after the submit event was sent) using [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement)

You can see if a `formaction` override is attached to the button that sent the submit event, otherwise if there is none, then use the original `action`

```js
document.getElementById("FORM").addEventListener("submit", handleForm);

function handleForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // for this example only

  let formAction = e.target.getAttribute("action");
  let activeElementAction = document.activeElement.getAttribute("formaction");
  let action = activeElementAction || formAction;
  console.log(action);
}
```

```html
<form id="FORM" action="/original">
  <input type="text">
</form>

<button form="FORM">original</button>
<button form="FORM" formaction="/formaction">formaction</button>
```

Comment: Thx @andrew-lohr, a bit hacky but does the job.

Comment: Unfortunately in recent versions of mac Safari, `document.activeElement` is the `<body>` element, not the clicked and focused button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `submitter` property of `SubmitEvent` and check that `formaction` attribut is filled
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent

This property is referenced in `originalEvent` property of JQuery submit event

```
var submitter = $(event.originalEvent.submitter)

if (submitter.attr('formaction')) {
    ...     
} else {
    ...
}
```