# How to get the form action on submit when using the formaction attribute on a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

A `<form>` has different buttons. On the submit event I would like to know what button was clicked. I had the idea that the `formaction` attribute on the button could be used for this. On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction) it says that the `formaction` attribute:

> Overrides the action attribute of the button's form owner.

But when getting the form action this value does not change according to the `formaction`. So how can I get the value of `formaction` or do you have any other suggestions for solving this?

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log(e.target.action);

  switch (e.target.action) {
    case 'a':
      // do "a" stuff
      break;
    case 'b':
      // do "b" stuff
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="default">
  <button formaction="a">A</button>
  <button formaction="b">B</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `value` to `button`  and then use `submitter` as below.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log(e.submitter.value);

  switch (e.submitter.value) {
    case 'a':
      // do "a" stuff
      break;
    case 'b':
      // do "b" stuff
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="default">
  <button value="a">A</button>
  <button value="b">B</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm after. We can always discuss if the value attribute should be used here and if there should also be a name attribute. It depends on the use case. In my case it could be fine.

Comment: @chrwahl check edited simplified solution I had gave which answer your question that you "would like to know what button was clicked"

Answer (score 2):

Check out `e.submitter`. it'll give you the element that submitted the form

Comment: e.submitter will not get action value which override by `formaction` attribute on the button as per asked question,

This question moreover seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988827/how-to-get-formaction-in-submit-event

Answer (score 0):

If a `formaction` is attached to button to override submit event then you need to grab the element which have current focus after submit event is sent therefore  to grab active element value use [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let action = document.activeElement.getAttribute("formaction");

  console.log(action);

  switch (action) {
    case 'a':
      // do "a" stuff
      break;
    case 'b':
      // do "b" stuff
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="default" method="get">
  <button formaction="a">A</button>
  <button formaction="b">B</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that this would work, but at the same time I consider it a bit "hacky". In the call back function I like to "stay in the context" of the event. But here you need to ask "outside" that scope. I know it is not part of my question, but I would like to open up for the possibility to dispatch an event on the button without clicking it and in that case the button would not be the active element.